# Powershell optimization (scripts to run simultaneously)

Tags: performance, csv, powershell, compression

I need some help here, I posted on stackoverflow and was directed here, just to put things in context, I am new to PowerShell, I have a task, that in simple terms, would take a csv with more than 2Million records (coming from BigFix) and a lot of columns, break it into multiple CSVs, by selecting specific columns, so the code below is my attempt to get this done, and the CSVs created will be zipped.Issues, with only 200 thousand records, this took about 4hrs, so first i don't know if there's a way to Import-Csv once rather than importing it each time i have to select different columns for output? Besides the copying task in the beginning (need to be first) and the Zipping need to be after all the CSVs are created, the rest can run at the same time (i don't know how to do that) Thanks for any help

```
$filePath = "C:\location2\powerShellTesting\Input\bigFixDataNew.csv"

Copy-Item "\\location1\20191213_BFI_SAMPLE_DATA_csv.csv" -Destination $filePath




$System = "..\Output\System.csv"
$AddRemove = "..\Output\AddRemove.csv"
$GS_PC_BIOS = "..\Output\GS_PC_BIOS.csv"
$GS_PROCESSOR = "..\Output\GS_PROCESSOR.csv"
$GS_LOGICAL_DISK = "..\Output\GS_LOGICAL_DISK.csv"
$GS_X86_PC_MEMORY = "..\Output\GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.csv"
$GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM = "..\Output\GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.csv"
$GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM = "..\Output\GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.csv"
$GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS = "..\Output\GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.csv"



$desiredColumnsAddRemove = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'Component Name'}; label ='DISPLAYNAME'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Product Version'}; label = 'VERSION'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Publisher Name'}; label = 'PUBLISHER'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Creation'}; label = 'INSTALLDATE'}

$desiredColumnsGS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'Server Vendor'}; label = 'MANUFACTURER0'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Server Model'}; label = 'MODEL0'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Partition Virtual Processors'}; label = 'NUMBEROFPROCESSORS0'}

$desiredColumnsGS_OPERATING_SYSTEM = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'Operating System'}; label = 'NAME0'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Operating System'}; label = 'CAPTION0'}

$desiredColumnsGS_WORKSTATION_STATUS = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Last Scan Attempt'}; label = 'LASTHWSCAN'}

$desiredColumnsSystem = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'DNS Name'}; label = 'NAME'},
@{ expression = {$_.'User Name'}; label = 'USER_NAME'}

$desiredColumnsGS_X86_PC_MEMORY = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' }

$desiredColumnsGS_PROCESSOR = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'Vendor'}; label = 'MANUFACTURER0'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Processor Brand String'}; label = 'NAME0'}

$desiredColumnsGS_PC_BIOS = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' },
@{ expression = {$_.'Server Vendor'}; label = 'MANUFACTURER0'},
@{ expression = {$_.'Server Serial Number'}; label = 'SERIALNUMBER0'}

$desiredColumnsGS_LOGICAL_DISK = @{ expression = {$_.'Internal Computer ID'}; label = 'RESOURCEID' }




Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_X86_PC_MEMORY -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_X86_PC_MEMORY –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_PROCESSOR -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_PROCESSOR –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_PC_BIOS -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_PC_BIOS –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_LOGICAL_DISK -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_LOGICAL_DISK –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_OPERATING_SYSTEM -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_WORKSTATION_STATUS -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsSystem -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $System –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsGS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM –NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv $filePath | Select $desiredColumnsAddRemove |
Export-Csv -Path $AddRemove –NoTypeInformation



# Creating the Zip File
$compress = @{
    Path = "..\Output\AddRemove.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.csv" ,
    "..\Output\GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.csv",
    "..\Output\System.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_X86_PC_MEMORY.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_PROCESSOR.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_PC_BIOS.csv",
    "..\Output\GS_LOGICAL_DISK.csv"

    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath = "..\Output\BigFix.Zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress -Force
```

Comment: Have you considered implementing part of this in other tools such as excel with VBA?

Comment: No because the output of BigFix is so large that even excel can't handle it, and the ultimate goal is to create the 9 csv that you see there for consumption by another tool, and that tool expects that in that format. So I am taking a large csv breaking it into smaller ones, renaming some columns...

Comment: Use a variable for the imported CSV: `$ImportedCSV = Import-Csv $filePath` Then pipe that to each `Select` statement: `$ImportedCSV | Select $desiredColumnsGS_X86_PC_MEMORY -Unique |
Export-Csv -Path $GS_X86_PC_MEMORY –NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichMoss this question was initially posted on stackoverflow (no intention of duplicating, but a user who commented suggested i come here) and this is the exact suggestion i received there.

Comment: the `Select-String` cmdlet can accept a file _directly_ and is apparently rather fast. [*grin*] it will accept a regex pattern ... so you otta be able to have that pattern capture the columns you want and spit them out as new lines.